# ¿A qué se refieren las tramas?

Tags: soporte

El día de hoy navegando en el sitio, me encontraba dando revisión a algunas preguntas y me apareció un mensaje un poco extraño que nunca había visto, el mensaje es el siguiente:

> Por motivos de seguridad, no se permiten las tramas; haz clic en Aceptar para quitar las tramas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El procedimiento que seguí fue muy sencillo:

1. Abrir la pregunta [Tablas en SQL SERVER](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111035/tablas-en-sql-server)
2. Dejar un comentario al OP
3. Dar clic en el botón <kbd>←</kbd> para regresar a la lista de preguntas y justo ahí fue cuando me apareció la alerta

¿A qué se debe este comportamiento? ¿Creen que ya rompí el sitio :( ?

Comment: Creo que sí, lo has roto. Desde que hiciste eso me salen alarmas rojas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La traducción es un poco rara, pero buscando algo equivalente en inglés encontré en Meta Stack Overflow [“For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames” on every page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265627/1983854).

En la respuesta, un desarrollador explica:

> This message is the result of code we've specifically written to check for other sites opening Stack Exchange Network sites in an iframe.

Es decir, que este mensaje aparece si cargas una página de Stack Exchange a través de un iframe. No sé si es tu caso, pero por allí explican que puede que aparezca porque algún malware esté operando desde tu ordenador.

Comment: Siempre abro las páginas de SE y SO directamente en el navegador. Revisaré la opción del malware, es posible que esa sea la razón del mensaje :( muchas gracias como siempre :)

Comment: @Flxtr faltaría más :) Veo que aceptaste la respuesta, ¿quiere decir que era el caso? Para descartar otras hipótesis, vaya.

Comment: Me temo que sí era un problema de malware, he corrido un análisis del antivirus y detectó algunas amenazas, de igual forma he intentado replicar el comportamiento y ya no ha pasado ;)

Comment: @Flxtr qué bien. Sugiero que añadas el siguiente elemento en tu lista de cosas a hacer: instalar Linux ;-)

Comment: Entonces la traducción está mal, debería dejarse como *frames* o traducir como "marcos".

Comment: @blonfu sí, llevas razón. He sugerido una traducción en [Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2865/83): _Por motivos de seguridad, no se permite trabajar desde frames; haz clic en Aceptar para quitar los frames_.

Comment: @fedorqui He actualizado el mensaje original con el que sugeriste - el tuyo me parece menos torpe y más lógico. :D

Comment: @JuanM qué bien, ¡muchas gracias! Lo [marco como estado-completado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2865/83)